# Location of Outlook certificate warning setting

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, ssl, certificate

My hosting provider misconfigured their email server using a self-signed certificate that had CA=TRUE set.  Only way I was able to retrieve business emails for a few days was to tell Outlook to accept that certificate.  Now that the hosting provider has fixed it I'd like to back out that trust setting but I cannot find it.

- The cert does not appear to be in the Windows certificate store
- I cannot find anything in Outlook that allows me to back out that trust setting
- That cert DN is not found in the registry

Obviously I've overlooked something.  Outlook *must* store that somewhere.  Any ideas?

Comment: If you clear IE's stored SSL cache you should solve your problem.  [here](http://www.thefixerblog.com/2013/05/clear-ssl-certificate-cache-for-outlook.html) and [here](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/40179/is-there-an-ssl-certificate-state-cache-on-windows-ie-and-outlook-and-how-it-i)

Comment: Ah, and I'm guessing it stores those encrypted which is why I don't find it in the registry?  I should have saved the cert off in PEM and I could search for the hex bits.  Damn!  Put that as an answer if you want the points.  Thanks!